# Where is Reset Security Token option in salesforce

Tags: security-token

Users can obtain their security token by changing their password or resetting their
security token via the Salesforce.com user interface by following the path Your Name
| Setup | (Personal Setup) | My Personal Information | Reset My Security Token,
and then clicking on the Reset Security Token button.

The above option is not visible in salesforce.com website.

Comment: Make sure your Profile does not have an entry in the "Login IP Ranges" related list on the profile assigned to your user. If it does, then you will not get a security token as your access is restricted by IP range

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below path

Your Name > My Settings > Personal > Reset My Security Token

Comment: This option is not available.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my Sandbox on Winter 17. I can't find any option to reset security token despite I don't have any IP restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this happens if your organization restricts the IP addresses from which you can log in. You need to whitelist your IP address. Go to Security Controls --->> Network Access and add your IP here.

You can also refer the link below for more details:

> > https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000182450